# What is the difference between “mistake me” and “mistake what I say”？

Tags: differences

In my textbook there is a sentence, “Listen to me carefully so as not to misunderstand me”.

Can we also say “mistake what I say”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### They are similar enough, with some difference...

Short Answer: Yes, either one can be used for the example given.

Longer Answer:

The two phrases are close enough to be used interchangeably in general, especially in casual conversation. Still, "misunderstand me" can be deeper than "mistake what I say": to mistake what someone says is just about that one thing they say. Meanwhile, to "misunderstand" someone can mean you do not fully recognize who they are or what they are about. But again: generally, the two will be interchangeable in casual conversation.

Comment: Thank you for all your help